# react-spring parallax smooth scrolling not working when sticky

Tags: reactjs, parallax, sticky, smooth-scrolling, react-spring

I'm using the Parallax and ParallaxLayer components from React-Spring to make a website with parallax effect. Putting the speed to 1 like so makes the text scrolling "smooth", meaning it glides into places instead of moving at a constant speed when scrolling:

```
<ParallaxLayer speed={1}>
    <h2 text </h2>
</ParallaxLayer>
```

However, when I use another property - `sticky` - to make the text be unaffected by scrolling for a certain distance, this "smooth" effect stops working.

```
<ParallaxLayer speed={1} sticky={{ start: 0, end: 0.75}}>
    <h2 text </h2>
</ParallaxLayer>
```

Are these two properties just not combinable? If so, is there another way to achieve either of them, so both work at the same time?